# i m making report by using jsp... I want to know how can i add total of each column at the end of every page on clicking print()

Tags: mysql, jsp

i am using limit 0,25 in the query but it remain fix all time, So is it possible to change the value of limit offset while page changes.
I mean how i can change the offset value by clicking print button.

```html
<form>
                <%  int yr1=0;
                    
                    if(request.getParameter("year")!=null)
                {
                    yr1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
                }
                     int yr=yr1+1;
                     int preyr=yr1-1;
                 SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           java.util.Date dd=new java.util.Date();
           String cdate=format1.format(dd);
           
            %>
           <span style="text-decoration: none;float: right; margin-top:0px; font-size: 12px;" id="print"><a href="#" onclick="P()">Print Page</a></span>
             <h2 style=" text-align: center">Date: <%=cdate%></h2>
            <h1 style=" text-align: center">Working Statement of Share, Loan, Interest Etc. For Year (<%=yr1+"-"+yr%>)</h1>
              
         <table>
             <%  String month=request.getParameter("month");
            String year=request.getParameter("year");
            String zone=request.getParameter("zone");
            String categ=request.getParameter("categ");
            String rank=request.getParameter("rank");
            long lopbal=0;
            long totlopbal=0;
            long lpaid=0;
            long totlpaid=0;
            long totalloan=0;
            long lrecd=0;
            long totlrec=0;
            long balon31=0;
            long stot=0;
            long spaid=0;
            long srecd=0;
            long lastsbal=0;
            long totlastsbal=0;
            long totsdep=0;
            long totspaid=0;
            long totint=0;
            long totirec=0;
            long totalin=0;
            long totalinrec=0;
           int i=1;
          
            %>
            
            <tbody><tr><td colspan="13"><hr></td></tr>
                    <tr  class="td-border">
                        <td><b>SNO</b></td>
                        <td><b>NAME</b></td>
                        <td><b>ACNO</b></td>
                        <td><b>OPEN BAL</b></td>
                        <td><b>TOTAL PAID</b></td>
                        <td><b>TOTAL RECD</b></td>
                        <td><b>BAL ON 31 MAR</b></td>
                        <td><b>LAST S BAL</b></td>
                        <td><b>SHARE RECD</b></td>
                        <td><b>S PAID</b></td>
                        <td><b>S TOTAL</b></td>
                        <td><b>TOTAL INT</b></td>
                        <td><b>TOTAL RECD</b></td>
                        
                    </tr>
               <tr><td colspan="13"><hr></td></tr>
          <%          
           try
             {   PreparedStatement ps=null;
                 ResultSet rs=null;
                 PreparedStatement ps1=null;
                 ResultSet rs1=null;
                 PreparedStatement ps3=null;
              
                 
              Connection con=Connect.connectDemo();
           ps=con.prepareStatement("select name, ledger_number, member_account_number, ob_share,total_share, jan_share, feb_share, march_share, apr_share, may_share, june_share, july_share, aug_share, sep_share, oct_share, nov_share, dec_share, paid_share from  member_details where fin_year='"+year+"' or posting='"+zone+"' or category='"+categ+"' or rank='"+rank+"' limit 0,25");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
                 {%>
               <tr>
                   <td><%=i%></td>
                   <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                   <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
               <% lastsbal=rs.getLong(4);
                 srecd=rs.getLong(6)+rs.getLong(7)+rs.getLong(8)+rs.getLong(9)+rs.getLong(10)+rs.getLong(11)+rs.getLong(12)+rs.getLong(13)+rs.getLong(14)+rs.getLong(15)+rs.getLong(16)+rs.getLong(17);
                 spaid=rs.getLong(18);
               stot=rs.getLong(5);
           ps1=con.prepareStatement("select opening_balance, jan_loan_given,feb_loan_given,march_loan_given,apr_loan_given,may_loan_given,june_loan_given,july_loan_given,aug_loan_given,sep_loan_given,oct_loan_given,nov_loan_given,dec_loan_given, jan_loan_recovered,feb_loan_recovered,march_loan_recovered,apr_loan_recovered,may_loan_recovered,june_loan_recovered,july_loan_recovered,aug_loan_recovered,sep_loan_recovered,oct_loan_recovered,nov_loan_recovered,dec_loan_recovered,bal_on_31_mar, jan_int_due,feb_int_due,march_int_due,apr_int_due,may_int_due,june_int_due,july_int_due,aug_int_due,sep_int_due,oct_int_due,nov_int_due,dec_int_due,jan_adj,feb_adj,march_adj,apr_adj,may_adj,june_adj,july_adj,aug_adj,sep_adj,oct_adj,nov_adj,dec_adj,jan_int_recovered,feb_int_recovered,march_int_recovered,apr_int_recovered,may_int_recovered,june_int_recovered,july_int_recovered,aug_int_recovered,sep_int_recovered,oct_int_recovered,nov_int_recovered,dec_int_recovered from  loan_details where loan_account_number='"+rs.getString(3)+"'");
            rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
            if(rs1.next())
            {
                lopbal=rs1.getLong(1);
              
           lpaid=rs1.getLong(2)+rs1.getLong(3)+rs1.getLong(4)+rs1.getLong(5)+rs1.getLong(6)+rs1.getLong(7)+rs1.getLong(8)+rs1.getLong(9)+rs1.getLong(10)+rs1.getLong(11)+rs1.getLong(12)+rs1.getLong(13);
           lrecd=rs1.getLong(14)+rs1.getLong(15)+rs1.getLong(16)+rs1.getLong(17)+rs1.getLong(18)+rs1.getLong(19)+rs1.getLong(20)+rs1.getLong(21)+rs1.getLong(22)+rs1.getLong(23)+rs1.getLong(24)+rs1.getLong(25);
           balon31=rs1.getLong(26);
           totint=(rs1.getLong(27)+rs1.getLong(28)+rs1.getLong(29)+rs1.getLong(30)+rs1.getLong(31)+rs1.getLong(32)+rs1.getLong(33)+rs1.getLong(34)+rs1.getLong(35)+rs1.getLong(36)+rs1.getLong(37)+rs1.getLong(38))+(rs1.getLong(39)+rs1.getLong(40)+rs1.getLong(41)+rs1.getLong(42)+rs1.getLong(43)+rs1.getLong(44)+rs1.getLong(45)+rs1.getLong(46)+rs1.getLong(47)+rs1.getLong(48)+rs1.getLong(49)+rs1.getLong(50));
          totirec=rs1.getLong(51)+rs1.getLong(52)+rs1.getLong(53)+rs1.getLong(54)+rs1.getLong(55)+rs1.getLong(56)+rs1.getLong(57)+rs1.getLong(58)+rs1.getLong(59)+rs1.getLong(60)+rs1.getLong(61)+rs1.getLong(62);
           totlopbal=totlopbal+lopbal;
           totlpaid=totlpaid+lpaid;
           totlrec=totlrec+lrecd;
           totalin=totalin+totint;
           totalinrec=totalinrec+totirec;
            }
            else
            {
             lpaid=0;
             lrecd=0;
             balon31=0;
             totint=0;
             totirec=0;
            }
          %><td><%=lopbal%></td>
            <td><%=lpaid%></td>
            <td><%=lrecd%></td>
            <td><%=balon31%></td>
            <td><%=lastsbal%></td>
            <td><%=srecd%></td>
            <td><%=spaid%></td>
            <td><%=stot%></td>
           <td><%=totint%></td>
           <td><%=totirec%></td>
           <%  
           totlastsbal=totlastsbal+lastsbal;
           totsdep=totsdep+srecd;
           totspaid=totspaid+spaid;
            i++;
                }
          long grandltotal=totlopbal+totlpaid;
           totalloan=grandltotal-totlrec;
         long grandstotal=totlastsbal+totsdep;
         long sharebal=grandstotal-totspaid;
            %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="13" align="center"><hr></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Total</b></td><td></td><td></td><td><b><%=totlopbal%></b></td><td><b><%=totlpaid%></b></td><td><b><%=totlrec%></b></td><td></td><td><b><%=totlastsbal%></b></td><td><b><%=totsdep%></b></td><td><b><%=totspaid%></b></td><td></td><td><b><%=totalin%></b></td><td><b><%=totalinrec%></b></td>
            </tr>
</tbody></table></form>
```

Comment: Show us your code. what have you tried?

Comment: i have mentioned the code...

Comment: It's not helpful to post your entire code and ask us to discern it to answer your non-question. Please debug your code and ask a single question that we can help you with

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the limit value of query. For example:

```
limitvar, offset=25

if (pageno == 1){
    limitvar = 1;
} else {
    limitvar = offset * pageno;
}
```

Make one variable which pass pageNo to query.at the time of query execution use that page no var. now use limit limitvar, 25. use your own logic with this way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your loop of display is this way...

```
<c:if test="${not empty listGood}">
<c:set var="total"/>
     <c:forEach var="ob" varStatus="status" items="${listGood}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ob.measure}"/></td>
       <c:set var=total value="${total + ${ob.price}}"
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>${total}</td>
</tr>
   </c:if>
```

Like this.